# Document Library - show a list of different one

Tags: 2013, web-part, document-library, document

I need you advise regarding **Document Library** in **SharePoint 2013**.
Setting up a Doc Library is straight forward but here is where I am stuck:

I have 2 departments **IT** and **HR**. Each of the department have their own Standard Instruction documents. So, I went ahead and created a **Document Library** in **IT** and one in **HR** and uploaded their relevant documents into their library.

Now, they want me to show their documents on the main page.

> rather showing 2 individual libraries - they want it to be shown as one

In my opinion, it is like merging 2 tables into 1.
However, I been looking into QUERY webPart but I got lost and not getting anywhere. Sorry, I am a newbie and willing to learn though.

Please advise and please don't talk to me in high-end-developers language.

Many Thanks in advanced.

PS: I have so many other questions to ask really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your requirement you have to use **`Content Query WebPart`**. Its easy to implement as you are new to SharePoint.

You can find more detail regarding using Content Query WebPart to show data from multiple list here [Display data from multiple lists with the Content Query Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-d560f477-8fc1-4258-aeb2-70aa932e07da)

There is another approach also which uses SharePoint Designer. You can create DataView using SharePoint Designer. You can find short detail here
[Two SharePoint lists in DataView - Linked Sources with SharePoint Designer](http://sp2013.blogspot.in/2013/11/two-sharepoint-lists-in-dataview-linked.html)

Comment: thanks for your advise :) the Content Query WebPart is the one I started with but then I was lost in it ... lol. Will try again and see if I can get a result. 

Whereas the SharePoint Designer mmmmh, I have it installed on my computer but not really confident using it. Will have to look into it in the future once I get a bit more into SP.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Content Search webpart since it's easier, the processes are below:

1. Insert a content search webpart, edit and change query
2. Since you want to get documents, choose "only return items" and hit "Add keyword filter"

[image]

3. Add those two libraries' ID that you can find it in the URL when you click the library setting. Manually type in ListID={xxxxxxxxx}

[image]

[image]

In the result preview section, you will see the items rolling up from both libraries.

Comment: the only webpart I find is "Content Query" under Content Rollup, which looks different to the screenshot you provided. Is this something that needs to be enabled in Features or does it depend on the SP version?!

Comment: @Bucki If the CQWP is the only one you saw, I wonder if you are using SharePoint Foundation? (the free version)  Since you can't target two specific libraries in CQWP, you would need to create a content type in Site Setting, associated the content type with those two libraries, and tag all documents from IT and HR with that content type. In your CQWP, you will choose to get data from that content type :)

Comment: we seem to have the SP2013 Server Edition ...